# How to increase performance for cost of appearance in Windows 7 RDP connection?

Tags: windows-7, performance, remote-desktop

I am searching for method to increase Windows 7 speed, via RDP. I mean, I need better performance. I know, I searched for solutions and already followed them up, but maybe there is something else to do?

I did `Remote Desktop Connection > Show Options`
As in [How to increase performance of Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/13487/how-to-increase-performance-of-remote-desktop)

In VPS `Performance Options` known also as `Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows` option. From my own experience.

Is there maybe something else to do?

Comment: Please include in your answer which solutions you found and applied.

Answer (score 0):

What are you ping times between the client and rdp host? If they are very high, ~500ms or more, there really is not much you can do to improve the remote desktop experience.

RDP is an amazingly efficient protocol in terms of bandwidth. It is by nature highly interactive though, and therefore very sensitive to latency.